# ProcessBuilder spawned process behaviour when modifying PB config

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

My question is:

**Do changes in ProcessBuilder environmental variables or working directories have an effect on PREVIOUSLY spawned processes?** Simple tests on Debian 9 and Windows 7 suggest that **there's no effect on already created processes**, but I'd like to be sure that it is the expected behaviour, preferably having some link to official docs or some explanation about the internals of ProcessBuilder which makes that statement unnecesary.

Details:

I'm using Process Builder in a concurrent system to spawn instances of the same process with different environment variables and working directories from multiple threads.

I'm currently using a ProcessBuilderControler class which avoids the typical concurrency problems by synchronizing the access to PB in order to avoid problems like the following when T1 and T2 attemp to spawn a process at the same time:

- T1 sets working dir of PB with value "/dir"
- T2 sets working dir of PB with value "/dir2"
- T1 executes start() of PB
- T2 executes start() of PB

In this case, T1 and T2 processes would have spawned scripts with /dir2 as working dir.

My concern was that MAYBE if you changed pb directory even after the process is spawned, the process would get the latest value. This was not the case in windows or linux according to my tests in which I forced the described situation..

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html): “Modifying a process builder's attributes will affect processes subsequently started by that object's `start()` method, but will never affect previously started processes or the Java process itself.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is a general limitation of the OS's that you cannot change the *environment variables* and the *working directory* of a running process from outside the process.

It might be possible using debugging APIs, but that is certainly not something `ProcessBuilder` would do.

---

> I'm currently using a ProcessBuilderControler class which avoids the typical concurrency problems by synchronizing the access to PB in order to avoid problems

The correct way to avoid concurrency problems, when using `ProcessBuilder` in a controller class, would be to not use a shared instance of `ProcessBuilder`.

That is actually a general *recommendation*: Don't use shared mutable objects in controllers.

Comment: Thanks. What would you do in my case? Just start a new ProcessBuilder every time I want to start a process?

Comment: @DGoiko "correct way" = "not use a shared instance" = "new ProcessBuilder every time" = "what I would do". --- `ProcessBuilder` is just a [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), i.e. a class to help collect information needed to create a complex object (`Process`). Not seeing any of your code, I don't know what you believe would be saved by using a shared object. Why do you believe creating a new (very short-lived) `ProcessBuilder` wouldn't be the right thing to do?

Comment: It is meant to be used hundreds if not thousands times, most times with sasme arguments in most cases, so I just wanted to make it more efficient.

Comment: Considering the huge amount of processing resources needed by your computer to actually start a new process, the minuscule amount of code needed to construct a `ProcessBuilder` is nothing. This is a great example of misapplied performance consideration. Besides, with shared access of mutable `ProcessBuilder`, you'd have to synchronize access to it, losing maybe even more than you gained by sharing.

Comment: Thanks! I'm following your suggestion and change my approach